# ORA-00979: выражение не является выражением GROUP BY

Tags: oracle, group-by

Всем привет. Подскажите коллеги, что я делаю не так, либо мне не по глазам.
Посмотрите своим взглядом.

> [Error] Execution (1: 1): ORA-00979: выражение не является выражением
> GROUP BY ORA-06512: на  line 14 ORA-06512: на  line 14

Ругается на строку, которая идет после  *FOR result_rec IN (*

```
DECLARE
  v_start_date DATE := TO_DATE('2024-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
  v_end_date DATE := TO_DATE('2024-01-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
  v_section_number NUMBER := 1;

BEGIN
  FOR section_rec IN (SELECT maingroup, undergroup, minigroup
                      FROM v_sectiongroup
                      WHERE store = 'МАГАЗИН'
                        AND minigroup IS NOT NULL
                        AND numbersection = v_section_number) LOOP

    FOR result_rec IN (
    SELECT maingroup AS Отдел,
           'Секция ' || undergroup AS Секция,
           LISTAGG(insumm, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY undergroup, minigroup) AS "Товарооборот, руб",
           LISTAGG(outsumm, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY undergroup, minigroup) AS "Реализация, руб",
           ROUND(SUM(outsumm - insumm), 2) AS "ТН,(руб.)",
           ROUND(SUM(outsumm * 100 / CASE WHEN SUM(insumm) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE SUM(insumm) END - 100), 2) AS "ТН,(%)"
    FROM v_rentab_full
    WHERE (maingroup, undergroup, minigroup) IN (
      SELECT maingroup, undergroup, minigroup
      FROM v_sectiongroup
      WHERE store = 'МАГАЗИН'
        AND minigroup IS NOT NULL
        AND numbersection = v_section_number
    )
      AND cddate BETWEEN v_start_date AND v_end_date
      AND storecode = 'МАГАЗИН'
    GROUP BY maingroup, undergroup  -- Добавлены maingroup и undergroup для группировки
  ) LOOP

      -- Вывод результатов
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(result_rec.Отдел || ', ' || result_rec.Секция || ', ' ||
                           result_rec."Товарооборот, руб" || ', ' || result_rec."Реализация, руб" || ', ' ||
                           result_rec."ТН,(руб.)" || ', ' || result_rec."ТН,(%)");

    END LOOP;

  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: Попробуйте так `GROUP BY maingroup, 'Секция ' || undergroup`

Comment: Не прокатило. Точно такая же ошибка.

Comment: У Вас в запросе есть такое выражение: `.. SUM(outsumm * 100 / CASE WHEN SUM(insumm) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE SUM(insumm) END - 100) ..`. CASE содержит внутри константу и агрегаты, то есть оно всё вместе является агрегатом. Однако Вы его заворачиваете в ещё одну агрегатную функцию. Понятное дело, сервер обиделся. А что сообщение об ошибке невменяемое - так это обычное дело.

Comment: Даже с исправлением. Выдает тоже самое.

Comment: исправьте так: `ROUND(SUM(outsumm * 100) / CASE WHEN SUM(insumm) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE SUM(insumm) END - 100, 2) AS "ТН,(%)"`